# Why is that updating problem after just installing ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
```

Answer (score 0):

This means that some updating software is already running. If you are using the terminal to do `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-upgrade` be sure that the Software Center and Synaptic are **closed**.